# Firefox struggling about d3.js svg library?

Tags: javascript, firefox, svg, d3.js

I coded some d3.j code that is svg visualization library and in my Mint installation firefox is really bad for rendering it. Is it about my installation or is it the general case?

[Here is a example link](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/talk/20111018/collision.html) for d3.js example

Comment: If you grab a Firefox nightly and toggle the preference described at http://www.hackermusings.com/2012/05/firefoxs-graphics-performance-on-x11/ does that help?

Comment: It might work but having nightly version also can cause ant additional problems I guess.

Comment: It shouldn't, no.  Just run the nightly against a different profile from your normal Firefox install.

Comment: mike's example works well everywhere on my computer... the only place where I have seen problems with D3 so far is IE<9 in general. can you be more specific about the problems you ran into? flickering? missing objects? transitions that are too slow?

Comment: transitions that are too slow..

Comment: I have same problem, FF 19 has up to 9x slower performance regarding d3 forced layout with nodes and links than Chrome or Ie9

Answer (score 2):

Almost 2 years later, and the animation in FF is still a problem with FF29. It's a shame.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Transitions are very slow in FF 15 compared to Chrome and Safari. But you should try FF beta or Aurora. They come with significant performance improvements for SVG transitions and d3.js. My transitions are now running smoothly.